Contextual Boundaries with Scripture
Is it contextually incorrect to consider the woman with the issue of blood story in Mark 5:25 as a representation of our living with sin and how we are made clean by Jesus?
Seeing that she probably never would’ve been able to make atonement by the law due to her illness, thus we can never atone for sin except by Jesus.
If this view is correct and/or possible, where/how do we draw the line concerning context with scripture  when the stories can have hidden meanings, typology etc.?

The key to understanding any Bible passage, especially those in the Gospel is the grasp three matters:

incongruities
the conclusion that is reached/pronounced (if any)
what the story teaches about the nature, work and ministry of Jesus

1. Incongruities
In the story of the woman with the issue of blood, incongruities abound - there are more than a dozen such as any casual reader will readily see. Here are a few:
First, the story (Mark 5:21-43) of the woman with the issue of blood is wrapped within the story of the dying child and these are constantly compared and contrasted

the girl was 12 years old - ready for her bat mitzvah; the woman had been sick for 12 years
the central matter in the healing of both was faith/belief (the words are the same in Greek)
both had exhausted all human means of cure
the woman was bleeding, and so was "unclean", which means she should not have been anywhere near a crowd much less in a crowd.  It was illegal for her to touch anyone for fear of ritual uncleanness and contamination.  However, her hand's touch on Jesus, far from being contaminating Jesus, healed her.  Similarly, Jesus healed the sick girl (actually resurrected her) by a touch on the hand.
Jesus called the woman "daughter".  Similarly, the girl is Jairus' daughter.
etc (there are many more)

2. Conclusion
The matter that Jesus concludes out these stories in Mark 5 is the centrality of trust/faith - the sick were powerless to heal themselves had to completely trust Jesus to do the work.  Very little of Jesus' words are recorded in Mark 5 except these salient matters:

V34: “Daughter,” said Jesus, “your faith has healed you. Go in peace and be free of your affliction.”
V36: But Jesus overheardd their conversation and said to Jairus, “Do not be afraid; just believe.”
V41: Taking her by the hand, Jesus said, “Talitha koum!” which means, “Little girl, I say to you, get up!”

3. Teaching about Jesus
"Jesus" means "Jehovah saves".  It is this that is so ably demonstrated here - Jesus uncontaminated by sin; indeed, when Jesus came into contact with sin - He healed and forgave.  Compare the story of the crippled man let through the roof in Mark 2:1-12 - the first thing Jesus did was to forgive before even healing.

Hmmm..
Yes.  That view is perfectly correct; the idea is clear and what you see is what you get here.
Regarding parables, stories, etc.  Some are open for interpretation and others are specific and the message is clear.
The man who bought a field and gave everything he had because it had a pearl of great price [The field being the world, the pearl of great price - His own, and the cost was the death of Christ.
But the rich man and Lazzareth that gives us clarity on how to treat people, where the good and evil were kept, and the dire consequences of a cruel heart are clear. Many discount this as a "story" but the fact a person was named and there are very clear details given here, is different. Many stories can be symbolic and/or have hidden meanings but certain ones, the interpretation is clear as in Lazzareth and the rich man, and the woman that came to Jesus.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to the site, massageps, and thanks for your answer. You make a good point about the differences between parables and actual events with real people. Parables are meant to teach lessons, to make hearers think about their spiritual significance, while the woman here was just as real as Jesus, as was the resurrected Lazarus. Could you enlarge your answer a bit to deal with the OPs query, "how do we draw the line concerning context with scripture" as the OP seems to think this woman is "a story"?
